# How do I create multiple objects of a (game character) class dynamically in c++

Tags: c++, oop, object

I have to modify my program and create a new (Gamefigures) class from which my current classes(Rabbit and Hedg) inherit. The code is a small game where two animals race until they reach the goal, but in the second task I have to make sure that it is possible that multiple iterations of these animals can race. (5 vs 5 or X vs X for instance). I am allowed to move some variables or methods to the `Gamefigures` class. Both of the animals use different rules to walk. How do I make a new class which creates multiple objects dynamically of the same class from which my current classes inherit?

I have tried to use the new expression to create a new object but I don't know if it is the right thing to do.

I tried:

`Hedg* nHedg = new Hedg[numFigures];`

Here is the rest of my code:

```
class Hedg: public Gamefigures
{
private:
    int salat = 1;
protected:
    int position1 = 0;
public:
    bool turn(int fields)
    {
        int counter = 10;
        if (fields < 11)//Less than 10 fields
        {
            while ((counter > 0))
            {
                if (counter < fields)//max 10 fields
                {
                    fields = counter;
                }
                position1 += fields;//walk
                counter -= fields;
                if (counter <= 0)
                {
                    salat = 0;
                }
            }
            getSalat();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    Hedg()
    {
    }
    int getPosition1()
    {
        return position1;
    }
    int getSalat()
    {
        return salat = 1;
    }
    int getStock1()
    {
        return salat;
    }
    ~Hedg()
    {
    }
};

class Game :public Hedg, public Rabbit
{
private:
    int goal = 0;
    int numFields = 0;
protected:
    Rabbit theRabbit;
    Hedg theHedg;
public:
    Game();
    Game(int numFields);
    int getGoal();
    int dice();
    void doyourturn();
    bool getStand();
    ~Game();
};
```

Here is the error message:

`Error code C4430 missing typespecifier`

Comment: Please read this: [ask]. Then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: You'd better use `std::vector<Hedg>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Hedg>>` and avoid raw `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) is what you need for your use case and will solve your problems.

Let's suppose you have a base class for your animals:

```
class Animal
{
    // ...
    // Create all the (pure) virtual methods to be redefined by a derived class
    virtual void walk() = 0; // For example
};
```

Then you defines your two specific animals, the rabbit and the hedgehog:

```
class Rabbit : public Animal
{
    // ...
    // Redefine here the (pure) virtual methods of Animal for a Rabbit
    void walk() override;
};
class HedgeHog : public Animal
{
    // ...
    // Redefine here the (pure) virtual methods of Animal for a HedgeHog
    void walk override;
};
```

And you can use polymorphism to handle your list of animals:

```
std::vector<Animal*> race_competitors;
race_competitors.push_back(new Rabbit);
race_competitors.push_back(new HedgeHog);
```

And this way, when you will call the `walk()` method over a competitor, it will automatically execute the proper walking rule of the corresponding animal.

Of course, at the end of the race, don't forget to `delete` the content of the vector because the animals was created with `new` ("manually" allocated memory, on the heap).

---

Just for information, the `Game` class doesn't have to inherit from `Rabbit` and `HedgeHog`, it just has to know them as class members, or even better, store a `std::vector<Animal*>` as a list of competitors.

I hope it will help you to improve your design and solve your problems.